# flutter compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion on Android

Tags: android, flutter

I would like to know that if I want my app to support new Android phone which api level is 9.0(Pie), what value should I set for `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` on `build.gradle`.
Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android 9 has API level 28. Full list [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element?utm_campaign=adp_series_sdkversion_010616&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#ApiLevels).

Answer (score 43):

### compileSdkVersion : version actually used to build the app

It's usually recommended to use the Flutter constant for the `compileSdkVersion` to always compile with the latest version of the SDK supported by Flutter : `compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion.`

### targetSdkVersion : compatibility mode at runtime

You can also use the constants for the `targetSdkVersion` but you can define a lower number if you have not tested your app on the latest Android OS.

### minimumSdkVersion : minimum level of devices that will run your app

The `minimumSdkVersion` value should never be lower than `flutter.minimumSdkVersion` but can be higher if you want to be more restrictive (or if you use a dependency that requires you to raise the bar).

To be able to use your app on Android Pie (API 28), your `minimumSdkVersion` should be greater or equal to 28.

## Simplified example of `/android/app/build.gradle` :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.bundle.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}
```

#### Minimum and maximum values for Flutter

The Flutter constants are declared in this file : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy#L45

Extract as of March 19th, 2024 :

```dart
    public final int compileSdkVersion = 34
    public final int minSdkVersion = 21
    public final int targetSdkVersion = 34
```

Of course they can change with every revision of Flutter

Comment: Why are flutter constants so out of date? At the time of writing this Gradle version in flutter is 4, current Gradle version is 8! Target android API is 31 and Google requires devs you to target 33. I'd say do not use flutter defaults, instead change this to a more recent version

Answer (score 15):

Flutter needs `minSdkVersion` 16 and you can set the `targetSdkVersion` along with `compliedSdkVersion` to the latest API level which is 30 currently.

You can edit these properties in file `/android/app/build.gradle`.

```
minSdkVersion 16
compiledSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30
```

> By August 2021, new apps must target at least Android 11 (API level 30). By November 2021, all apps that are being updated must target at least Android 11 (API level 30). Until then, new apps and app updates must target at least Android 10 (API level 29).