# Could not find method compileSdkVersion()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build an android app bundle release but am getting an error that says ''Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [21] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.'' I have tried reading about it but all in vain. The terminal specifically says that line 36 has the issue. The code block is just above the compileOptions{} code block. I have tried putting the code block in braces but does not work. I also tried flutter clean then the
flutter build appbundle but the same error kept coming up.Here is how my android/app/build.gradle looks like

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
  

android //this is the line 36 in my code
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion 
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.eduself"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

     signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }


flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then this is the error my terminal throws after I run the flutter build appbundle.

```
PS C:\final> flutter build appbundle

 Building with sound null safety 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\final\android\app\build.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [21] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              9.1s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS C:\final>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
```

without any parentheses, its because you used some features or packages that are not available for current compile sdk and need to upgrade

i suggest to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977807/flutter-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion-on-android)

Comment: Thank you so much mohammad esmaili. I have tried that but its creating another bug

Comment: your welcome, what is problem

Comment: I have changed the compileSdkVersion to what you suggested but it keeps throwing the same error. I probably think compileSdkVersion() is a method somewhere else in the project most likely packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle. But I cannot find it.