# Give me some explainatioin about minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion in flutter

Tags: flutter, sdk, build.gradle, android-sdk-manager

As at some point in flutter project we developers need to modify our project **build.gradle** file in our project so can someone give me the complete guide about these 3 version numbers and their simplified meaning with brief explaination?

I tried different websites and docs of the flutter gradle but I am unable to find any satisfactory solution of my question in my mind about these three versions I mentioned before.

Comment: You should include in your post which websites you've read which do not satisfy your question. [This page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element) from the Android Developer Guide should be clear enough explaining those three.

Comment: Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71691454/6656661

Comment: That was so helpful thanks for ur assistance deaar Dharini